# android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f080074

Tags: android

I have a very complex set of android code and layout files, but I keep seeing this error

> android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f080074

Comment: Don't add all your code to the question. Create a separate [mcve] that reproduces the problem

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately your question is not understandable at all . 
But anyway, try clicking on File > Invalidate Caches/restart in Android Studio it may help .

Edit:

After editing your question I may now be able to answer you :

This error message is triggerd, when you are trying to get any type of resources from `R` object, that doesn't exist .

try cleaning your project in android studio by clicking on Build > clean project and then rebuilding it using Build > rebuild project .
Hope it works .

Comment: To insert a code in your post, copy your code and paste it in your question and then select it with your mouse and click on the icon {} to format it as code